# Flutter app volume automatically goes low after watching a rewarded ad or interstitial ad

Tags: flutter, dart, google-ads-api

I'm encountering an issue on iOS with the volume settings after watching a rewarded ad or interstitial ad in my app. The problem specifically occurs on iOS devices, while the functionality works fine on Android.

After the ad finishes, the app's volume automatically decreases significantly on iOS, causing a noticeable reduction in audio playback. This behavior is not observed on Android devices.

I'm utilizing the google_mobile_ads package version 2.3.0 and the audioplayers package version 4.1.0 in my Flutter application.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or potential solutions to address this volume issue on iOS after ad playback.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.